# How can I rewrite this Kotlin filter method more succinctly?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of strings. I want to search given a query string and say I only want the first 10 matching strings. Here is what I tried, the first one does exactly what I want.

I was wondering if there is a succinct way of writing it.

```
fun search(query: String): ArrayList<String> {
    val found = ArrayList<String>()
    for (i in terms.indices) {
        if (terms[i].contains(query)) {
            found.add(terms[i])
        }
        if (found.size == 10) {
            break
        }
    }
    return found
}
```

I wanted to use this one but as you can see this is not as efficient as the above one because it goes through the whole list

```
fun search2(query: String): List<String> {
    return terms.filter { it.contains(query) }.take(10)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a [`sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html) should give you what you want:

```
fun search2(query: String): List<String> {
    return terms.asSequence().filter { it.contains(query) }.take(10).toList()
}
```

You might not need the `toList` if you're fine with keeping a sequence as result.

Comment: Useful link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html

Comment: but this one is not as efficient as search1 since it will have to go all the way through the list find the once that much and reduce the result to 10. but whereas the first method just goes through the list finding the one that much and breaks (returns)once it found 10 of them.if i have a very big list which i do. if the first 10 matching strings are at the beginning, this method will still iterate through all of them.

Comment: @lpkiss nope, see how sequenes work. "Sequence performs all the processing steps one-by-one for every single element" so after 10 elements matching the predicate have been found, execution stops.